# How can I initiate a call on the press of a Button?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am in the process of building an app for my business. I would like to include telephone numbers and when a user presses the telephone button - I would like for that to call our business. 

My question is.. is there a way to set up a button that when pressed...will call us? 
I am using Eclipse
I am using Windows XP
I am using android 3.2

I know it is very easy to do using jquery in Dreamweaver 6.0...but I want to make my app better -- so I am trying to pick up Java along the way of developing this app.

Comment: As far as I am concerned, Honeycomb (3.2) doesn't have any telephone features at all.

Comment: Force,

What should I do? Should I upgrade to 4.0? If I do that..will those running 3.2 have the ability to access 4.0? How can this be done?

Comment: Well, either use Android 1.5-2.3 or 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this and it is incredibly easy to do. Essentially all you need is this intent:

```
String phoneNumber = "tel:123456789"
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(phoneNumber));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Comment: There are lots of tutorials online that explain how to do this a simple google search for "Android SDK Place Phonecall" would have found them

Comment: Hello Slayton,

I just added it to my class.
Now, how do I get it displayed?
Do I need to go ahead and add the button?

Comment: You need to execute this code somehow. Ideally you would attach a ButtonListener to the button and execute this code in the listeners `onClick` method. Here is an example: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-button-example/  This is all really basic stuff. I suggest you buy a book about android development and read through that, something like this would work: http://www.amazon.com/Android-Absolute-Beginners-Wallace-Jackson/dp/1430234466/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1325190791&sr=8-1